# Laravel not downloading on Wamp using Composer

Tags: laravel, wamp, composer-php

I have installed Composer in `C:` drive and installed Wamp in `D:` drive.

Now I want to  download Laravel using composer through this command line:

`composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"`

However, it shows the following error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information

Installing dependencies (including require-dev)

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.


  Problem 1

    - The requested package laravel/framework could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.


Potential causes:

 - A typo in the package name

 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting 

see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> for more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

Can you please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: you can directly download laravel project without downloading installer with `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`

Comment: Thanks, but I want to install laravel version 4.x instead of 5 as my Wamp currently supports PHP 5.4. So, can you please let me know the command prompt /code to download laravel 4..2 or something?

Comment: I have used this command to download laravel version 4.2.11: 
composer create-project laravel/laravel YOURFOLDERNAME 4.2.*

Comment: Cool i hope its done :)